# What´s the best solution to improve the speed of a python loop that iterates over a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

If anyone has time to take a look at this issue. What´s the best way to increase the processing speed of this function? It gets very slow if it has to deal with more than 50 000 values.Thank you.

Data is a 2d numpy array.

```
def mean_error(data): 
    sub=[]
    for i in range(len(data)):
        soma=abs(data[i][0]-data[i][1])
        sub.append(soma)
        mean_error=np.sum(sub)/len(sub)
    return mean_error
```

Comment: Try looking into tensorflow

Comment: What is `self.feedforward`?  For that matter, what is `self`?

Comment: You can get rid of the loop with slicing. Also, don't use `len` for numpy arrays, use shape instead.

Comment: A first step could be pulling `mean_error=np.sum(sub)/len(sub)` out of the `for` loop...

Comment: Please, could you tell me why you called the temporary variable `soma` rather than `diferença` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't this basically the same code?

```
def mean_error(data):
    soma = np.abs(data[:, 0] - data[:, 1])
    return (np.cumsum(soma) / np.arange(1, data.shape[0] + 1))[-1]
```

You calculate cumulative sums inside the loop and add them to `sub`. You calculate those sums of differences of the first column with the second column... You don't need a loop for that, there's slicing for that.

This can even be simplified because you don't use `mean_error` inside the loop, you only need it in the end (in the above code shown with `[-1]`, but in that case `cumsum` is not necessary at all):

```
def mean_error(data):
    soma = np.abs(data[:, 0] - data[:, 1])
    return np.sum(soma) / data.shape[0]
```

Comment: no, it's not the same code, OP is not accumulating the `mean_error`, he simply returns the final result.

Comment: good point, thanks. I only need to access the last element of what I am currently returning and then it is the same thing (at least the difference of OPs method with my method then returns zero for a 10x10 random array). Thank you @gboffi!

Comment: rather than the last element, isn't it simpler:  `np.sum(soma)/data.shape[0]` ??

Comment: Yep, added that. Now I understand your comment under OPs question, btw ;-)

Comment: Thank you for your help.